# std::set erase complexity anomality?

Tags: c++, stl, time-complexity, stdset

I am trying to figure out the complexity of erasing multiple elements from std::set. I am using [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/erase) as source.

It claims that the complexity for erasing a single item using an iterator is amortized O(1), but erasing multiple items using the range form is log(c.size()) + std::distance(first, last) (i.e. - log of the set's size + the number of elements deleted).

Taken at face value, if the number of elements to be erased (n) is much smaller than the number of elements in the set (m), this means that looping over the elements to be erased and erasing them one at a time is quicker (O(n)) than erasing them with one call (O(log m) assuming n<<m).

Obviously, had that really been the case, the internal implementation of the second form would just do the above loop.

Is this an error at the site? A bug in the specs? Am I just missing something?

Thanks,
Shachar

Comment: _erasing multiple items using the range form is log(c.size()) + std::distance(first, last) (i.e. - log of the set's size + the number of elements deleted)._ - with fixed set's size is scales exactly as O(n) where n is number of elements deleted, which is what you get from deleting them one by one.

Comment: That's interesting, I guess you could test it both ways to see the difference. Maybe there would be some overhead in resetting the iterator after each individual erase (as I think this invalidates the iterator)

Comment: @Cthulhu, the same logic applies whenever a plus is used in complexity. Anything you assume constant (or even bounded) automatically has complexity of O(1).

Answer (score 6):

Internally elements of a set are stored in a balanced binary tree. Balanced tree is a tree where maximal height difference between any left and right subtree of any node is 1.

Maintaining balanced structure is important to guarantee that a search of any element in the tree (in the set) takes in worst case `O(log(n))` steps.

Removal of an element may destroy balance. To restore balance rotations must be performed. In some cases a single removal causes several rotations so that the operation takes `O(log(n))` steps, but in average a removal takes `O(1)` steps.

So, when several elements scattered over the set must be deleted, one by one, the amortized costs with high probability will be `O(1)`  per removal.

Removing several elements in the range (`first, last`, where one element follows the next) will almost certainly destroy the balance, what causes the log factor in the complexity: `log(n) + std::distance(first, last)`

Answer (score 2):

It seems the problem is hiding behind the (somewhat weasel) word "amortized". The single item erase has O complexity of log(c.size()), but amortized complexity of O(1).

Performing multiple single erases in a loop will thus cost log(c.size()) + number of erases, which is exactly what the range form's complexity is.

Shachar

Comment: "amortized" is not a weasel word. It's a well-established computer science term: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis.

Comment: Okay, "weasel" is a bit harsh. I do think that dropping the strict upper bound statement fosters confusion. If you only provide the amortized complexity of an operation, you often deprive a programmer the ability to know what to expect.

I agree that using ONLY the O complexity can be equally misleading (as in here), but I do think the standard should have mentioned both.